Pass document ID from one page to secound page - Flutter firestore database
I created new document on FirstPage and I can print his docAtricle.id (auto id created in firestore database). I can't pass this object to Secound Page. I tried few metods but without any results. I would like to put it as a value to the next page
class NewTravelPageInformation extends StatelessWidget {
  NewTravelPageInformation({super.key, required this.value});
  
  final TextEditingController nameOfTheTravel = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController descriptionOfTheTravel = TextEditingController();
  final String value;

  @override
        onPressed: () {
          createNewArticle(nameOfTheArticle: name, descriptionOfTheArticle: description);
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/secoundpage');
            Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => SecoundPage(value : value),),);
.
.
.

  Future createNewArticle({required String nameOfTheArticle, required descriptionOfTheArticle }) async {
    final docArticle = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user.uid).collection('Articles').doc();

    // Create document and write data to Firebase
    await docArticle.set({
      'name': nameOfTheArticle,
      'description': descriptionOfTheArticle,
      'Article_id': docArticle.id,
      'user_id': user.uid,
    });    
    // print the id of the created Article
    print(docArticle.id);

In the first Page I command that he need to create New Document and now I would like to get this docArticle.id and pass it to Secound Page becouse I would like create new collection "Information" in this document
class SecoundPage extends StatefulWidget {
  String value;
  SecoundPage({super.key, required this.value});
@override
  State<SecoundPage> createState() => _SecoundPage(value);
}

class _SecoundPage extends State<SecoundPage> {

  String value;
  _SecoundPage(this.value);

Future createNewInformation({required String nameOfTheInformation, required descriptionOfTheInformation}) async {
    final docInformations = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user.uid)
    .collection('Articles').doc(widget.value).collection('Informations').doc();

    await docInformations.set({
      'name': nameOfTheInformation,
      'description': descriptionOfTheInformation,
    });
  }

Is my method correct and how to pass object docArticle.id ??
